# Pthreads: My parallel code does not pass threads into the function after a certain amount

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am currently creating a parallelized code using MPI to find out how many triangles are in any given graph. Thus far, my code is able to successfully get the correct amount of triangles (I know because I have a serialized version of the same code, which runs a lot slower) until a certain point. I would say that after about 6000 nodes my threads are no longer being read within the function (I discovered this by looking at the threads in the main function vs counting  whether the thread made it into the function).

For reference, the code itself takes in a number of nodes, edges, seed, and degree.

For this purpose we will ignore the seed and degree as they work perfectly fine when everything is working.

Edit: I will quickly explain the variable naming convention for those lost. Essentially we are given a graph of multiple nodes along with the edges connecting them (think adjacency list). Now the job of the program is to go through each vertex u, and take another vertex v within the graph to find if they have a corresponding vertex w that connects between them. In this situation, since there are no bools in C we will be using ints for the edges uv, uw, and vw. In this way if there is a connecting edge then we can turn these to a 1. If they are all 1 then we have found a triangle and can now add it to the global variable. Let it be known that the code here within the for loops of figuring out the triangles is 100% correct and is not the issue of the question. Rather the question involves the problem of utilizing the pthreads at higher nodes.

Here is the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "graph.h"

#define MAX_N       1000000
#define MAX_E       2*MAX_N // must be at least twice MAX_N

GRAPH_t * G;    
#define MAX_THREADS     65536
#include <pthread.h>


int thread_id[MAX_THREADS]; // User defined id for thread
pthread_t p_threads[MAX_THREADS];// Threads
pthread_attr_t attr;        // Thread attributes 

pthread_mutex_t lock_count; // Protects minimum, count

unsigned int parallelCount = 0;
unsigned int threadCount = 0;
void *count_ParallelTriangles(void *threadID) {

  int u = *((int *)threadID);
  int counter = 0;

  unsigned int v, w, e, uv, uw, vw;
  for (v = u + 1; v < G->n; v++) {
    uv = 0;
    for (e = G->V_ptr[v]; e < G->V_ptr[v + 1]; e++) {
        if (G->E_v[e] == u) {
            uv = 1;         // Edge (u,v) exists
        }
    }
    if (uv == 1) {
        for (w = v + 1; w < G->n; w++) {
            uw = 0; vw = 0;
            for (e = G->V_ptr[w]; e < G->V_ptr[w + 1]; e++) {
                if (G->E_v[e] == u) uw = 1;     // Edge (u,w) exists
                if (G->E_v[e] == v) vw = 1;     // Edge (v,w) exists
            }
            if ((uv == 1) && (vw == 1) && (uw == 1)) {
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
    }
  }
  //if (counter > 0) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_count);
    threadCount += 1;
    parallelCount += counter;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_count);
  //}

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and below is where it is being called in main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

struct timespec start, stop;
float time_serial;

unsigned int num_nodes, num_edges, seed, num_triangles, max_degree;

if (argc != 5) {
  printf("Use: <executable_name> <num_nodes> <num_edges> <seed> 
  <max_degree>\n"); 
  exit(0);
}
if ((num_nodes = atoi(argv[argc-4])) > MAX_N) {
  printf("Maximum number of nodes allowed: %u\n", MAX_N);
  exit(0);
}; 
if ((num_edges = atoi(argv[argc-3])) > MAX_E) {
  printf("Maximum number of edges allowed: %u\n", MAX_E);
  exit(0);
}; 
if (num_edges < 2*num_nodes) {
  num_edges = 2*num_nodes;
  printf("Number of edges must be at least twice the number of nodes: changing 
  num_edges to %u\n", num_edges);
  exit(0);
}; 
seed = atoi(argv[argc-2]);
max_degree = atoi(argv[argc-1]);

// Initialize graph
G = init_graph ( num_nodes, num_edges, seed, max_degree );

float time_parallel;

//Initialize Pthread
pthread_mutex_init(&lock_count, NULL);
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
for (int u = 0; u < num_nodes; u++) {
    thread_id[u] = u;
    pthread_create(&p_threads[u], &attr, count_ParallelTriangles, (void 
  *)&thread_id[u]);
  }
  for (int u = 0; u < num_nodes; u++) {
    pthread_join(p_threads[u], NULL);
  }

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);

  time_parallel = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)
    + 0.000000001*(stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
  printf("Thread active: %d\n", threadCount);
  printf("Parallel execution time = %f s\n", time_parallel);
  // Print results
  printf("G: Nodes = %u, Edges = %u, Triangles = %u\n", G->n, G->m, parallelCount);

  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock_count);

  return 0;
}
```

And finally, here is my output when it is running correctly. The edges are set to max of 1000000 so it calculates the maximum amount of edges it can fit within its average degree which in this case is 234110.

```
./triangles.exe 4096 1000000 0 0
Serial execution time = 16.181034 s
G: Nodes = 4096, Edges = 234110, Triangles = 651015
Thread active: 4096
Parallel execution time = 0.843587 s
G: Nodes = 4096, Edges = 234110, Triangles = 651015
```

We can see that the above is working correctly as the amount of threads is equal to the amount of nodes declared. However if we increase the nodes by just a few thousand we see that the output no longer runs correctly, despite still going pretty fast:

```
./triangles.exe 6000 1000000 0 0
Serial execution time = 48.326824 s
G: Nodes = 6000, Edges = 413845, Triangles = 1207058
Thread active: 2061
Parallel execution time = 1.471421 s
G: Nodes = 6000, Edges = 413845, Triangles = 1079834
```

In the above case if we were to run this example a few more times the amount of threads will change between each call and the triangles it calculates will change as a result (since each triangle count is dependent on the thread properly passing it the to global variable). The serialized count and time will remain relatively consistent as it is already correct.

EDIT:
Added more code for the main file.

Below is the header file for creating the graph

```
typedef struct _graph {
  unsigned int n;       // Number of vertices in the graph
  unsigned int m;       // Number of edges in the graph
  unsigned int * E_u;       // Edge i = (E_u[i],E_v[i]) 
  unsigned int * E_v;       // 
  unsigned int * V_ptr; // Edges incident on vertex u 
  // have ids V_ptr[u] ... V_ptr[u+1]-1
} GRAPH_t; 

GRAPH_t * init_graph ( unsigned int n, unsigned int m, unsigned int seed, 
unsigned int max_degree ) {
GRAPH_t * G = (GRAPH_t *) calloc(1, sizeof(GRAPH_t)); 
unsigned u, v, e, nbrs, first, lastplus1, maxvalue;
double fraction;
G->n = n;
G->E_u = (unsigned int *) calloc(m, sizeof(unsigned int)); 
G->E_v = (unsigned int *) calloc(m, sizeof(unsigned int)); 
G->V_ptr = (unsigned int *) calloc((G->n+1), sizeof(unsigned int)); 

srand48(seed); 
unsigned int count = 0; 
// Generate edges 
G->V_ptr[0] = count;

for (u = 1; u < G->n; u++) {

G->V_ptr[u] = count;

switch (max_degree) {
    case 0:         // max_degree = 0 => max_degree = sqrt(n)
    nbrs = sqrt(G->n); if (nbrs > u) nbrs = u; 
    break;
    default:
    nbrs = max_degree; if (nbrs > u) nbrs = u;
    break;
 }

 first = G->V_ptr[u]; 
 lastplus1 = first + nbrs; if (lastplus1 > m) lastplus1 = m;

 if (first < lastplus1) {

   for (e = first; e < lastplus1; e++) 
     G->E_v[e] = ((unsigned int) lrand48()) % G->n;

     maxvalue = G->E_v[first]; 
     for (e = first+1; e < lastplus1; e++) {
       G->E_v[e] += G->E_v[e-1];
       maxvalue = G->E_v[e];
     }

     for (e = first; e < lastplus1; e++) {
       fraction = ((double) G->E_v[e])/(maxvalue+1+(lrand48()%G->n));
       G->E_v[e] = (unsigned int) (fraction * u); 
     }

     // Generate edges incident at u 
     G->E_u[count] = u; 
     G->E_v[count] = G->E_v[count]; 
     count++;
     for (e = first+1; e < lastplus1; e++) {
      if (G->E_v[count-1] < G->E_v[e]) {
         G->E_u[count] = u; 
         G->E_v[count] = G->E_v[e]; 
         count++;
       }
     }
   }
 }
 G->V_ptr[n] = count;
 G->m = count-1;        // Initialize number of edges

 // Check graph
 for (u = 0; u < G->n; u++) {
   if (G->V_ptr[u] > G->V_ptr[u+1]) {
      printf("Graph generation problem - 1!!!\n"); 
      exit(0); 
   }
   for (e = G->V_ptr[u]; e < G->V_ptr[u+1]; e++) {
      if (G->E_u[e] != u) {
        printf("Graph generation problem - 2!!!\n"); 
        exit(0); 
      }
      if (G->E_v[e] >= u) {
        printf("Graph generation problem - 3!!!\n"); 
        exit(0); 
      }
      if ((e > G->V_ptr[u]) && (G->E_v[e] <= G->E_v[e-1])) {
        printf("Graph generation problem - 4!!!\n"); 
        exit(0); 
      }
    }
  }
  return G;
}
```

Comment: You don't want `65536` threads running at the same time! Unless you have some big-iron system with with maybe hundred of cores and an operating system which can spread the load over all those cores. On a modern beefy system (like an 8-core/16-thread CPU) you will swamp the CPU and in effect have a denial-of-service attack by your own program, as the computer does nothing else than swap between your threads.

Comment: please post a full [MCVE]

Comment: Don't worry I am using a supercomputer to practice my work on. Its for university work. :P

Comment: as pointed earlier, creating one thread per task is highly unefficient, and you should use a pool of threads instead. That being said, do not do that and consider using `OpenMP` instead.

Comment: I am not sure if I can make it anymore minimal but if you need the rest of the main and the structure for the graph G i can certainly post that. Let me know! Also I am required to use MPI and pthreads for this problem, for those suggesting other parallel coding forms.

Comment: I am asking for "Complete and Verifiable", not a more Minimal one :-)

Comment: start by testing the value returned by `pthread_create()`

Comment: And please think about your variable naming... `unsigned int v, w, e, uv, uw, vw;`? What do all those do? How would anyone but you know what they mean? What about in a few months time when you come back to the program, and forgotten most about it? Same with `G`, `G->V_ptr`, `G->E_v` etc. What does it all mean? What are those variables used for? Brevity only for the sake of brevity is, IMO, useless. "The code is the ultimate documentation" only works if you have good descriptive names.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was code given by my professor and as part of the work I can only add to the overall program rather than change it. I can go back and change it for this stackoverflow however in order to help you all out. I also updated the post with more "Complete and Verifiable" data.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with @Someprogrammerdude. Those variable names are descriptive enough for me to understand in your graph context.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I tested the counts that are collected per thread and I didnt catch anything wrong with the proper counts returned, in fact what i discovered was that certain threads never even made it into the function in the first place. i tested this by using the above threadCount variable as well as some printf statements within the Mutex. We can see this in the command line output posted above which states the threads are less than the node count which shouldnt be the case as my main should be creating p_thread[nodes] overall.

Comment: did you check the value returned by `pthread_create()` ? but once again, you should really use `OpenMP` for that.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ahh im sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you meant the triangle values in each thread not the error values. After testing it seems the error value I am getting returned is 11 for pythread_create().

Comment: I actually find this interesting as the error code indicates that i have reached max threads. Despite this i have actually used up to 10,000 threads at one point using this supercomputer.  EDIT:  Actually I think I know the answer to this question, let me test for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized in my stupidity that I forgot that the supercomputer has a thread limit for executing programs on the command line and if you execute using a batch file in "dedicated mode" it is able to exceed beyond approximately 4096 threads. After testing this using a batch file I realized the error in my ways and this indeed was my solution. Sorry for the inconvenience yall! Hopefully this information helps other users in the future about checking your supercomputer's policies in regards to multi-thread computation! Thanks to Giles for making me check the error code as I wouldnt have realized that without the error code telling me I "ran" out of threads at 4096 (despite having about 65,536 haha). Once I am able to I will close the question.

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the bigger picture and you should not create so many threads. On KNL (68 cores), The test take 128 seconds with one thread, but less that 2 seconds with "only" 68 threads.

Comment: Oh I understand, it is complete overkill. However, this is a temporary program that wont be used beyond a certain thread limit and I was just trying to figure out what was going wrong, but thanks again for all the help in getting me to the answer!